# How to recode a character Outcome variable in a dichtomous Outcome (0,1) in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis, recode

I have a data set with cancer patients and different Outcomes

```
TypeofOutcome        DateStageIV

NA                   01.04.2014
Died from melanoma   01.06.2011
Died from melanoma   01.11.2013
```

I want a new column called "Outcome" with all patients still alive coded as 1 and all dead coded as 0.
From a previous exercise I created a code:

```
mergedData$Outcome <- 1* (mergedData$TypeofOutcome = c ("Alive with stable disease", "Alive with progressive disease", "Alive with complete response"))
```

I already assumed that this will not work and I got the Error message:

> Error in 1 * (mergedData$TypeofOutcome = c("Alive with stable disease",  :
>     non-numeric argument to binary operator

I am sure that there is a simple solution for my problem.

Comment: 1. I don't think your previous code does what you think it does (you need %in% here. 2. Is using regular expressions an option (search for 'died' in outcome.

Comment: Well coding it into dead/alive would be possible, too. I am kind of looking for something like (in words): Outcome = 1 if TypeofOutcome is Alive with stable disease or Alive with progressive disease...., Outcome = 0 if TypeofOutcome is Died from Melanoma, Died from other causes....

Comment: How do you want NA-values handled? You could do something like dat$outcome <- grepl("Died", dat$TypeOfOutcome)

Comment: NA-values should also be coded as 0. I will try your suggestion asap :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to create a dichotomous variable dependent on the value of a string variable, for example: if `TypeOfOutcome` matches any of  "Alive with stable disease", "Alive with progressive disease" or "Alive with complete response", `Outcome` would be 1 otherwise 0. I assume your dataset looks similar to this

```
mergedData <- data.frame(
  TypeOfOutcome = c("Alive with stable disease", "Alive with progressive disease", "Alive with complete response", NA, "Died from melanoma"), 
  DateStageIV = sample(seq(as.Date('2011/01/01'), as.Date('2015/01/01'), by="day"), 5))


#                    TypeOfOutcome DateStageIV
# 1      Alive with stable disease  2013-05-09
# 2 Alive with progressive disease  2014-08-08
# 3   Alive with complete response  2013-02-10
# 4                           <NA>  2014-05-23
# 5             Died from melanoma  2012-08-08
```

The function `ifelse` is suitable for this from of recoding, the basic syntax is:

```
ifelse(test, yes, no)
```

If the statment in `test` is true return the value of `yes` otherwise return the value of `no`. In this case `test` is all cases where the patient is still alive, which is indicated by the string in `TypeofOutcome` being "Alive with stable disease", "Alive with progressive disease" or "Alive with complete response". A test for this would be:

```
test <- mergedData$TypeOfOutcome %in% c("Alive with stable disease", "Alive with progressive disease", "Alive with complete response")
```

`test` would be `TRUE` if the value in `TypeOfOutcome` matches any of the cases after the `%in%` operator. `yes` would then be 1 and `no` would be 0. To create the new variable

```
mergedData$Outcome <- ifelse(test, 1, 0)

mergedData

#                    TypeOfOutcome DateStageIV Outcome
# 1      Alive with stable disease  2013-05-09       1
# 2 Alive with progressive disease  2014-08-08       1
# 3   Alive with complete response  2013-02-10       1
# 4                           <NA>  2014-05-23       0
# 5             Died from melanoma  2012-08-08       0
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for :) Thanks so much